# How to load GridView with Animations?

Tags: android, animation, android-gridview

I am trying animation on `GridView` similar to this http://framerjs.com/examples/preview/#delayed-animations.framer. I tried slideUp animation on `GridView` but all columns move at same point. I need it similar to the above link.

Answer (score 11):

Use GridLayoutAnimationController for grid item animation.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.grid_item_anim);
GridLayoutAnimationController controller = new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation, .2f, .2f);
mGrid.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

grid_item_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

add animate layout changes to true in your grid view layout

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Comment: This works but in ViewPager it causes to set current page to 0 and then move to the specific page with animation.

Comment: Please mark the answer as expected, as it worked for you

Answer (score 5):

Create a folder under "res" with name "anim" and inside "anim" create a xml file with name animation_move.xml(could be anyname).This app is using some animations in GridView .[Social Stickers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tenmb.social.stickers)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

and in your adapter class,do initialization

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.animation_move);
```

and in getview function,suppose you are using images

```
picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
picture.startAnimation(animation);
```

your getview function could be different but this code will give you hint.

Comment: Thanks...But not what I am looking for .. The animation is  bouncy

Comment: this is good guidance you add multiple animation files in anim folder. Its just an example.

Comment: yeah thats right I have got an idea from this  ....let me just try that....thanks..

Comment: This works but in ViewPager it causes to set current page to 0 and then move to the specific page with animation.